# Get the titles of a list of urls in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a Discord Bot and I want to show the queue in the music feature. It always send the urls and I cannot convert them to the titles of the websites. The code works but the question is how can I convert a list of urls into titles. My code:

```
@client.command()
async def view(ctx):
    global queue

    #convert url to title
    html = request.urlopen(queue[0]).read().decode('utf8')
    html[:60]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    title= soup.find('title')

    await ctx.send(f":page_facing_up: ・ Your queue: `{queue}`")
```

Comment: I'm not clear on where you're stuck.  You seem to understand that you have to extract the `title` information from the returned object.  Extracting a tag is a well-documented process.

Comment: I've already managed to convert a URL to a title. My question is how can I now turn a list of urls into a list of titles

Comment: You loop over the list of URLs and accumulate the corresponding titles in another list.  I'm still not sure where you're stuck.  Is it something related to the asynchronous operation?